# Resize chart and navigator

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I resize a chart and the navigator? In my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/8nenL/4/ the chart disappears, when the window is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{    
    chart.setSize(
       $(document).width(), 
       $(document).height()/2,
       false
    );   
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: container,
    spacingTop: 3,
    spacingRight: 0,
    spacingBottom: 3,
    spacingLeft: 0
},

navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    top: 330, // Abstand von oben
    outlineColor: '#C0C0C0',
    outlineWidth: 1
},

credits: {
    enabled: false
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a global problem with highstock, so I reported it to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2364